# Jquery UI Draggable and Swappable

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

This is my first time using jquery ui and the layout plugin. I've made several divs that need to be swappable essentially. I linked a jsfiddle of my current layout so you can see what I'm trying to do. I've attempted several solutions but they've been too buggy or moving the "pin" divs is really laggy. Do you have any possible solutions to make these "pin" divs easily drag and swappable? Below is an example of an item that should be drag and swappable.

```
 <div class="pinChildContainer">
      <div class="pins">
           <img class="pinImage" src="img/paymentServices.jpg" alt="Payment Services" width="188" height="185" />
           <p class="pinTitle">Payment Services</p>
      </div>
 </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qqx25vg8/3/

Comment: It is not clear to me what you would like to achieve. Do you want to be able to drag and swap a `<div class="pinChildContainer"><div class="pins">...` inside a `<div class="pinGroup">` ?

Comment: I want to be able to drag and swap <div class="pins"> between <div class="pinChildContainer">.

Comment: If you mean this [layout plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/layout/) than it is unclear to me what this has to do with [jqueryui.com/draggable](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/). Your jsfiddle-link seem to not include jquery-ui and does not contain any javascript. I you have tried several solutions but there were either to buggy or to laggy than why not include them in your fiddle?

Comment: This was the closest solution I tried: http://jsfiddle.net/39khs/82/  I forgot to include jquery-ui in the fiddle, thats my bad. This solution kind of worked but when swapping the pins the pins met and overlapped in the center of the screen and then swapped places. This solution was also laggy.

Comment: @Tyharo hmm.. not even your fiddle, so don't take credit! your css/html need serious cleaning up before you attempt to do this. Its not the solution that's 'laggy',  its your code. Its midnight here in ireland, but i'll post a fix in the morning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tyharo, I did a serious edit on your html/css before i did the solution so this is a trimmed down version. You had quite a lot of unnecessary classes/ divs within divs! Decluttering is good! :)

Now, because you have limited height and these are not divided into subcategories (you can do that bit yourself) - this example just swaps the one you drag from the beginning to the end. But they are draggable and swappable!

I'm not sure why you had it divided into 'rows' - seemingly of 3, when it came up on my fiddle as 2 initially, then 3 when i widened it, 1 when i narrowed it. If you want something to contain only a certain number of items, then give it a fixed width, although this is not advisable or should at least be adjusted with media queries. Think responsive!

Anyway, run the snippet! I'm tired..........zzzzzzzzzzzz.

Rachel

```js
$(".draggable").draggable();
var draggableArguments = {
  revert: 'invalid',
  helper: 'clone',
  appendTo: '#pins-container',
  refreshPositions: true,
  containment: 'DOM',
  zIndex: 1500,
  addClasses: false
};

$('.pins').draggable(draggableArguments);
$('.pins').droppable();

$('#pins-container').droppable({
  tolerance: "intersect",
  accept: ".pins",
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $('#pins-container').append($(ui.draggable));
  }
});
```

```css
#main-content {
  margin: auto;
  width: auto;
  /*background-color: orange;*/
  height: 700px;
  max-height: 700px;
}
#pins-container {
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  float: left;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
}
.pins {
  min-width: 270px;
  min-height: 280px;
  display: inline-block;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.pins:hover {
  transform: scale(1.03);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}
.pinTitle {
  font-size: 20px;
}
.draggable {
  border: solid 1px gray;
}
.pinImage {
  width: 188px;
  height: 155px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
<div id="mainContent">
  <div class="ui-layout-center">
    <div id="pins-container">
      <div class="pins" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="img/paymentServices.jpg" alt="test1" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test1</p>
      </div>

      <div class="pins" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="img/financialTargeting.jpg" alt="test2" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test2</p>
      </div>

      <div class="pins" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="img/processRatios.jpg" alt="test3" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test3</p>
      </div>

      <div class="pins" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="img/suitcaseOrdering.jpg" alt="test4" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test4</p>
      </div>

      <div class="pins" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="img/reassignPriorities.jpg" alt="test5" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test5</p>
      </div>

      <div class="pins" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="img/evaluateSecurity.jpg" alt="test6" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test</p>
      </div>
      <!-- End of Pins Container -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I created child divs, added 'sortable' (for which you have to add a float to the child pins), and created more pin classes so that children would be confined to within their own child div

View it here https://fiddle.jshell.net/RachGal/kueztcvr/show/

```js
$(".draggable").draggable();

var draggableArguments = {
  revert: 'invalid',
  helper: 'clone',
  appendTo: '#child1',
  appendTo: '#child2',
  appendTo: '#child3',
  refreshPositions: true,
  containment: 'DOM',
  zIndex: 1500,
  addClasses: false
};

$('#child1').droppable({
  tolerance: "intersect",
  accept: ".pins1",
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $('#child1').append($(ui.draggable));
  }
});

$('#child2').droppable({
  tolerance: "intersect",
  accept: ".pins2",
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $('#child2').append($(ui.draggable));
  }
});


$('#child3').droppable({
  tolerance: "intersect",
  accept: ".pins3",
  activeClass: "ui-state-default",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  drop: function(event, ui) {
    $('#child3').append($(ui.draggable));
  }
});

$("#child1").sortable();
$("#child2").sortable();
$("#child3").sortable();
```

```css
#main-content {
  margin:auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;  /*i changed this from 700 cos it resizes to the size of the pins container anyway*/
}

#pins-container {
  margin-left:17%;
  margin-right:17%;
  width: 100%;
  float:left;
  height: auto;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#child1,
#child2,
#child3 {
  max-width: 63%!important;   /*I was gonna put in max-width:850px here but better to have percentages*/
}

.pins1,
.pins2,
.pins3 {
  width: 272px; /*I left these but really they should be % too. Add media queries!*/
  height: 282px;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 1px;
  border: solid black 1px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.pins1:hover, .pins2:hover , .pins3:hover  {
  transform: scale(1.03);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -6px black;
}

.pinTitle {
  font-size: 20px;
}

.draggable {
  border: solid 1px gray;
}

.pinImage {
  width: 188px;  /*another case for media queries!*/
  height: 155px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<div id="mainContent">
  <div id="pins-container">

    <div id="child1">
      <div class="pins1" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="img/paymentServices.jpg" alt="test1" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test1</p>
      </div>

      <div class="pins1" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="FinancialTargeting.jpg" alt="test2" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pins1" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="FinancialTargeting.jpg" alt="test3" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test3</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="child2">
      <div class="pins2" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="img/processRatios.jpg" alt="test3" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test4</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pins2" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="img/suitcaseOrdering.jpg" alt="test4" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test5</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pins2" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="img/suitcaseOrdering.jpg" alt="test4" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test6</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div id="child3">
      <div class="pins3" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="img/reassignPriorities.jpg" alt="test5" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test7</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pins3" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="img/evaluateSecurity.jpg" alt="test6" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test8</p>
      </div>
      <div class="pins3" class="draggable">
        <img class="pinImage" src="img/evaluateSecurity.jpg" alt="test6" />
        <p class="pinTitle">test9</p>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the clean up and help! The swapping is close to what I was looking for but I was hoping to have the dragged item swap locations with the item its dropped over. Would this be difficult or a relatively simple solution?

Comment: Hey I just woke up again (after 2 hours sleep from what I can tell!) Did you not run the fiddle I left as a comment? That should work! The way you want I mean.... Any way.. Breakfast!!! Then code!

Comment: The commented jsfiddle does the thing, sends the dragged item to the end. I did however find what was causing the lag when dragging! The transition effects on the pins class was the culprit.

Comment: Thanks again Rachel, I greatly appreciate it!